# Automatically relocate fields with auto layout constraints, when one field is empty

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have the following xib file with `UITableViewCell`.

[image]

In the code, I have

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

This makes it so that the cells are self-sizing.  All of the auto layout constraints are set up correctly so that the cell will size itself and that works fine.

In the app, the Name and Maximum are required fields.  The remaining and total are calculated, and the Description is optional.  The cells look fine when there is both a name and description.  When the description is left off, there is a blank space left in the cell where the description would go.

[image]

Is there a way to adjust using the auto layout constraints, so that the Maximum, Remaining, and Total fields will be moved up to the Name field when the Description is not filled in?  Everything needs to move up to take over the space that the description would have occupied, and the cell needs to be shorter.

Comment: Just create an `IBOutlet` for the height constraint of `Description`. Set this constraint value to 0 when there is no description available. `descriptionHeightConstraint.constant = 0`.

Comment: This is a great idea, and works perfectly.  Thanks.